# Android show progress bar while image loading dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-asynctask

In one of my project, I am loading images from the dynamic url. Now I need to show the loading dialogue still all the images loads. I am loading the images using the Async task.
I am new to android. Please any one give me a little help

My code looks like.

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_1);
        for(Integer i=0;i<2;i++){


            TableRow rowP = new TableRow(this);
            rowP.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF000"));




            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            String ed="http://www.domain.com/image.jpg";
            image.setTag(ed);
            DownloadImagesTask td=new DownloadImagesTask();
            td.execute(image);

            rowP.addView(image);
            table.addView(rowP);
            }
        }


private class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

        Bitmap bmp =null;
        try{
            URL ulrn = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (null != bmp)
                return bmp;

            }catch(Exception e){}
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

```
private class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

        ImageView imageView = null;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        Context context;

        public DownloadImagesTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
            this.imageView = imageViews[0];
            return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            if (dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Title","Message");
        }

        private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

            Bitmap bmp =null;
            try{
                URL ulrn = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                if (null != bmp)
                    return bmp;

                }catch(Exception e){}
            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below lines in your `DownloadImageTask`.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Title",
                "Message");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (dialog != null)
        dialog.dismiss();
    //rest of the code
}
```

and declare `ProgressDialog dialog` in your `DownloadImageTask`.

To pass `Context`, you need to create a contructor for that.

```
private class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;

    public DownloadImagesTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    //... rest of code ....
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. and my code is running in an JSON loop.. in that time is this show multiple times ?

Comment: Most probably yes. If you don't want to show progress dialog, you can use progress bar inside view which will be there until download finished. When it gets finished, progress will disappear and image will be shown.

Comment: Hi, edited my code ? can you please check is that ok ? because I am getting an error ..

Comment: Yes its ok. but whenever you create object of task, you need to pass context like `DownloadImagesTask td=new DownloadImagesTask(this);`. It is missing. If I am not wrong. :)

Comment: Hi, one more question .. how to add the click event for the newly loaded image ?

Comment: `image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener)` will be fine. Pardon if I understand wrong..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep it simple/clear/fast and beautiful, you should not do the download yourself especially if you are new to android.

Just use an open source library:

**The easiest is** http://square.github.io/picasso/

Another more complex : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 3):

if you want to show progress on the progressbar you can use this code. It works like a charm.

Here dwBar is the progress bar. imView is the imageView you wanted to show picture.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dwBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {

                int increment;
                byte[] data;
                InputStream in = null;
                int response;
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect();

                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    }
                    int length = httpConn.getContentLength();

                    data = new byte[length];
                    increment = length / 100;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int count = -1;
                    int progress = 0;

                    while ((count = in.read(data, 0, increment)) != -1) {
                        progress += count;
                        publishProgress("" + (int) ((progress * 100) / length));
                        outStream.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                            outStream.toByteArray(), 0, data.length);
                    in.close();
                    outStream.close();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.d("Networking", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                    throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            dwBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm) {

            dwBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (bm != null) {
                imView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Like a charm indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete domanstration of actvity with downloading and showing image on screen.

Here is xml file for Activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Download Button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download File with Progress Bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"/>

    <!-- Image view to show image after downloading -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is Activity code.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AndroidDownloadFileByProgressBarActivity extends Activity {

  // button to show progress dialog
  Button btnShowProgress;

  // Progress Dialog
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  ImageView my_image;
  // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
  public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

  // File url to download
  private static String file_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/progressdialog/hive.jpg";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_download_file_by_progress_bar);

    // show progress bar button
    btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    // Image view to show image after downloading
    my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    /**
     * Show Progress bar click event
     * */
    btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // starting new Async Task
        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Showing Dialog
   * */
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
      pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
      pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
      pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      pDialog.setMax(100);
      pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      pDialog.setButton("Cancel", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
      pDialog.setCancelable(true);
      pDialog.show();
      return pDialog;
    default:
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Background Async Task to download file
   * */
  class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
      int count;
      try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress
        // bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
          total += count;
          // publishing the progress....
          // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
          publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

          // writing data to file
          output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
      }

      return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
      // setting progress percentage
      pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
      // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
      dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

      // Displaying downloaded image into image view
      // Reading image path from sdcard
      String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
          + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
      // setting downloaded into image view
      my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

  }
}
```

Just add this activity with following xml file.